# Java - Format DateTime taking TimeZone into account

Tags: java, date, timezone

1)
So, I have a date and time that is given to me in seconds, with the timezone offset in seconds as well.

eventTime = 1348880602 
eventTimezoneOffset = -180

2)
I am printing this out like this:

```
Date date = new Date(eventTime);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd, yyyy @ h:mmaa");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Which produces: Fri, Sep 28, 2012 @ 10:03PM

3)
However, this is for when I run it on my machine.

When I run it on my server, it gives me: Fri, Sep 28, 2012 @ 9:03PM

Because of the time difference on my server and my machine.

4)
So, I was trying to use the eventTimezoneOffset to set the Date or SimpleDateFormat objects to represent the time in the correct timezone time, regardless of where the server running the application is at.

5)
I tried to do this setting the timezone on the SimpleDateFormat, but was not sure how to do it using the eventTimezoneOffset in seconds that I have.

6)
To clarify, the events can take place all over the world.  Each event is tracked in seconds since Epoch.  So, when looking at just the eventTime, it will show for whatever timezone the application is running in. To get the exact time of the event, accounting for the location timezone, the timezoneOffet is provided. I'm just not sure how to apply the timezoneOffset.

Answer (score 0):

Set the timezone using the `SimpleDateFormat` instance's `setTimeZone` method:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd, yyyy @ h:mmaa");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: Well, I tried doing this, which resulted in a time of: Sat, Sep 29, 2012 @ 1:00AM. What I'm trying to do, is to use the timezone offset so that I can have the event time show up in the region where it took place, regardless of where the server running the application resides.  Make sense?

Comment: You should be able to see the solution to your problem within the question you asked.  It is a good practice to persist dates and times in UTC because it is a global, fixed point of reference.  In order to adjust from UTC, the appropriate locale must also be persisted (in some way) so that your code can determine the target offset(s).  If you are certain that your app will be used in only one timezone, then you needn't persist that info (you can use that timezone as a universal default). However if your app might span many locales, you'll also need to persist locale along with timestamps.